# Generating rows of panels with for loop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, for-loop

I would like to create rows of panels with textboxes using a for loop. 
The panels will be created inside another panel (MajorPanel).

The for loop's current value is used to assign values to the textboxes.

The number of rows will be determined by a form (form2) that has a textbox (RowNum) to input number of rows needed in the main form (form1) and use that information for the for loop's counter as shown:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click

    Dim Rows As Integer
    Rows = RowNum.Text 'RowNum is where to input number of rows needed in form1

    Dim TxtBoxPanel As New Panel
    Dim LeftBox As New TextBox
    Dim CenterBox As New TextBox
    Dim RightBox As New TextBox
    Dim YAxis As Integer ' for adding TxtBoxPanel in new row

    For index = 1 To Rows

        'adding the textbox panel

        Form1.MajorPanel.Controls.Add(TxtBoxPanel)  'referring to form1 as panel needed in form1
        TxtBoxPanel.Name = ("txtBoxPanel" & index)
        TxtBoxPanel.Size = New Size(610, 32)
        YAxis = +32
        TxtBoxPanel.Location = New Point(3, YAxis)

        'adding left box
        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(LeftBox)
        LeftBox.Name = ("LeftBox" & index)
        LeftBox.Text = (index)
        LeftBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        LeftBox.Location = New Point(3, 3)

        'adding center box
        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(CenterBox)
        CenterBox.Name = ("CenterBox" & index)
        CenterBox.Text = (index)
        CenterBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        CenterBox.Location = New Point(258, 3)

        'adding right box
        TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(RightBox)
        RightBox.Name = ("RightBox" & index)
        RightBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
        RightBox.Text = (index)
        RightBox.Location = New Point(495, 3)

    Next index

    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RowNum.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

However, when I execute, the panels generate one on top of the other as shown:

[After execution for 23 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdvQY.png)

This is the desired result I would like:

[Rows of panels within MajorPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdZKX.png)

form1 has only one line of code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a quick glance, it looks like you are using `YAxis = +32` when you should be using `YAxis += 32`.

The first one is just setting `YAxis` to the value 32, and the second one is incrementing it by 32, which is what you want (I assume)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1- You are adding same instance of TxtBoxPanel to MajorPanel which means it will overwrite the previous location and you will end up only having single TxtBoxPanel at the bottom of MajorPanel  because you are not creating new instead updating coordinates of same instance which got created before starting loop.

2- "YAxis = +32" should be "YAxis +=32

Here is updated code.. it should give you desired result.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click

        Dim Rows As Integer
        Rows = RowNum.Text 'RowNum is where to input number of rows needed in form1


        Dim YAxis As Integer ' for adding TxtBoxPanel in new row

        For index = 1 To Rows

            Dim TxtBoxPanel As New Panel
            Dim LeftBox As New TextBox
            Dim CenterBox As New TextBox
            Dim RightBox As New TextBox

            'adding the textbox panel

            Form2.MajorPanel.Controls.Add(TxtBoxPanel)  'referring to form1 as panel needed in form1
            TxtBoxPanel.Name = ("txtBoxPanel" & index)
            TxtBoxPanel.Size = New Size(610, 32)
            YAxis +=32
            TxtBoxPanel.Location = New Point(3, YAxis)

            'adding left box
            TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(LeftBox)
            LeftBox.Name = ("LeftBox" & index)
            LeftBox.Text = (index)
            LeftBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
            LeftBox.Location = New Point(3, 3)

            'adding center box
            TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(CenterBox)
            CenterBox.Name = ("CenterBox" & index)
            CenterBox.Text = (index)
            CenterBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
            CenterBox.Location = New Point(258, 3)

            'adding right box
            TxtBoxPanel.Controls.Add(RightBox)
            RightBox.Name = ("RightBox" & index)
            RightBox.Size = New Size(100, 20)
            RightBox.Text = (index)
            RightBox.Location = New Point(495, 3)

        Next index

        Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, because after changing ''YAxis=+32'' to ''YAxis +=32'' as suggested by you and @Magnus, only the last panel is generated. So how do I create all the other instances of 'TxtBoxPanel' and the textboxes without overwriting the previous ones?

Comment: I have shared code with the bug fix. you can you use it. I have moved the control's declaration inside the loop so, it will create a new instance of all required controls for each iteration.

Comment: @Amin84, since the solution worked for you so, it should be marked as answer.